# How to know presence of a file in a commit using JGit?

Tags: jgit

I am trying to find JGit API which can help to know whether a file exists in a commit.
As described [here](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/ReadFileFromCommit.java), I think I can use `RevWalk`, `RevCommit`, and `TreeWalk` to solve this.
But, I am curious whether JGit has any in-built API support for this?
Thanks.

Comment: `treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create("README.md")); if (treeWalk.next()) {` seems to be a  pretty straightforward way to do that, copied almost verbatim from the linked-to-source. What more do you need?

Comment: Note that jgit internal interfaces aren't really a Git thing, so the [tag:git] tag here is misplaced. It's also not a Java-the-language thing, so I think really only the [tag:jgit] tag is appropriate.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Actually, wanted to create a `RevFilter` for `LogCommand`... In `org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.filter.RevFilter#include` needed to check existence of a file given `RevCommit`. Above approach looked little verbose, curious of any existing API in JGit. With above approach I was able to solve the issue. Thanks.